# only update if value is not empty in foreach statement

Tags: php

I keep getting an error `Undefined property: stdClass::$` on any $li that is empty, is there a quicker way of not inserting the blank columns / fields? other than `if ($li->company != "")` I still want it to insert the non empty ones.

```
foreach ($data as $li) {

$insert['company']= $li->company;
$insert['first']= $li->first;
$insert['last']= $li->last;
$insert['email']= $li->email;
$insert['phone1']= $li->phone1;
$insert['phone2']= $li->phone2;
$insert['phone3']= $li->phone3;
$insert['address1']= $li->address1;
$insert['address2']= $li->address2;
$insert['address3']= $li->address3;
$insert['postcode']= $li->zip;
$insert['city']= $li->city;
$insert['country']= $li->country;
$insert['stage']= $li->stage;
$insert['source']= $li->source;
$insert['website']= $li->website;
$insert['user_ID']= is_user_logged_in();
$insert['owner']= is_user_logged_in();
$insert['assigneduser']= is_user_logged_in();

$insert['stage']= "Prospect";
$this->db->insert("leads", $insert);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isset()` to test if the property is set, and use a default value if it isn't.

```
$insert['company'] = isset($li->company) ? $li->company : "";
```

To avoid lots of repetition, you can use a loop:

```
foreach (['company', 'first', 'last', ...] as $field) {
    $insert[$field] = isset($li->{$field}) ? $li->{$field} : "";
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/lH1skN)

Comment: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)  is an error it is giving me :(

Comment: I just tested `var_dump(isset($li->{$field}))` and it worked.

Comment: @ScottO'connor But if I use `null != expression` I get an "Undefined property" error.

Answer (score 2):

In your Class constructor you can set a default value for all the attributes.

If you cannot modify the constructor, an alternative to have a better readable code is use the [ternary operators](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators), an one line `if` and `else` variation

For example:

```
$insert['company'] = (isset($li->company))? $li->company : "";
```

is the same as

```
if(isset($li->company))
  $insert['company'] = $li->company;
else
  $insert['company'] = "";
```

Comment: This will still report an error if the property isn't set.

Comment: You are right! I am editing the answer to consider it in the conditional clause

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a test for empty:

```
if($li->zip) {
  $insert['postcode'] = $li->zip;
}
```